# How to convert my htaccess code to php header

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, pdo

I have these lines of code in my .htaccess.

My problem is is this line of code is in my .htaccess i want to put it in my php.

I want to do is convert it to php header does anyone know how to do it?

```
AddType application/xml .xml .rss
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Try using `header()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even try to implement that yourself or read at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php?

Write those lines before the first output of the file.
Should do the job (although untested):

```
<?php
// ...
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
?>
```

Comment: how about the AddType application/xml .xml .rss?

Comment: That's an Apache directive telling that file ``xml`` and ``rss`` extensions are delivered with the mimetype ``application/xml``. Afaik it's not possible to directly map that within the header but implement code which checks what to send as mimetype. The code for setting the mimetype would then be ``header('Content-type: application/xml');``